# Finite order automorphisms of complex projective manifolds isotopic to identity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

**Question.** Let $V$ be a complex projective manifold of general type (we can even assume that the canonical bundle of $V$ is ample). Suppose $\varphi: V\to V$ is a non-identical automorphism. Can $\varphi$ be isotopic to the identity map (i.e. $\varphi\in Diff_0(V)$)?

I hope the answer is no, and this can be easily proven when $K_V$ is very ample.

More generally what restrictions are known on smooth manifolds that admit self-diffeos of finite order that are isotopic to identity?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer to your question is unknown already for surfaces $S$ of general type.

Note that, if $S$ is simply connected, by a result of Quinn (see "Isotopy of 4-manifolds", Journal of Differential Geometry 1986) every automorphism acting trivially on rational cohomology must be *topologically* isotopic to the identity.

At any rate, it seems that people conjecture that the answer to your question is **no** for simply connected surfaces of general type. See Catanese's paper "A Superficial Working Guide to Deformations and Moduli" (arXiv:1106.1368), Section 1.4  for further details. In this paper, complex manifolds which do not admit non-trivial automorphisms isotopic to the identity are called *rigidified*.

Comment: Francesco, huge thaks! This interesting, I am really surprised that this is yet unknown for surfaces of general type. 

Comment: Dear Dmitri, you are welcome. I was really surprised too, when I read Catanese's survey. This seems really a very basic and interesting question.
 

Comment: Francesco, Frank Quinn (J. Diff. Geom. 1986) shows that for a simply connected compact 4-manifold, $\pi_0$ of the group of homeomorphisms is the group of automorphisms of the intersection form. Is this what you are referring to? If so, isn't differentiable isotopy a different story?

Comment: @Tim: let $V$ be a simply-connected compact $4$-manifold and  $f \colon V \to V $  an automorphism acting trivially in cohomology. In particular  $f$ acts trivially on the intersection form of $H^2$. Therefore by Quinn's result (Theorem 1.1), it follows that $f$ must be in the identity component of $\pi_0 \textrm{Top}(M)$, i.e. $f$ is isotopic to the identity. I'm missing something?  

Comment: Francesco, Dmitri's question asked about differentiable isotopy, while Quinn's result is about topological isotopy. In dimension 4, there's a gulf between plain topology and differential topology...

Comment: @Tim: Ok, now I understand your objection. I think you are right, Quinn's theorem seems to deal only with topological isotopy. I do not know whether there is a similar result for differential isotopy. I will edit the answer, thank you for the remark.

Comment: Just for completeness, here's a reference to a gauge-theory paper proving the failure of Quinn's result in the differentiable category: D. Ruberman, Math. Res. Lett. 5 (1998), no. 6, 743–758.